# Null pointer in persistentBag in backing bean

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, jsf

I would like to know why I am getting null pointer in my bean method. On my front end I'm interating on value adp.domain.elementsDomain, since the labels are being properly displayed on the screen.
This is my front:

```
<c:forEach items="#{atributosDaPesquisaBean.atributosDaPesquisaList}" var="adp" varStatus="loop">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="20">
        <h:outputText  value="#{adp.dominio.nome}"/>    
        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="gridQueryResult" layout="grid" columns="2"> 
            <f:selectItems value="#{adp.dominio.elementosDominio}" var="elemento" itemLabel="#{elemento.label}" itemValue="#{elemento}" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{atributosDaPesquisaBean.incluiNaPesquisa(elemento)}"/>
        </p:selectManyCheckbox> 
     </h:panelGrid>
</c:forEach>
```

This is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AtributosDaPesquisaBean {

private List<AtributosDaPesquisa> atributosDaPesquisaList;

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        AtributosDaPesquisaDAO adpDao = new AtributosDaPesquisaDAO();
        atributosDaPesquisaList = adpDao.buscaPorRelatorio(relatorio.getCodigo());
        atributosDaPesquisaList.forEach(adp -> adp.setaClausulaDeData());
        for(AtributosDaPesquisa adp: atributosDaPesquisaList){
            if(adp.isEhDominio()){
                List<ElementoDominio> elementosDominio = adp.getDominio().getElementosDominio();
                elementosDominio.forEach(elemento -> elemento.setEstaNaPesquisa(false));
            }
        }
   }

   public void incluiNaPesquisa(ElementoDominio elemento){
     //here elemento comes as null. Why?
    elemento.setEstaNaPesquisa(true);
   }
```

}

And these are my models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_atributosdapesquisa")
public class AtributosDaPesquisa {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "atr_codigo")
private Long codigo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "tbl_dominio_dom_codigo", referencedColumnName = "dom_codigo")   
private Dominio dominio;

//others columns

//getters and setters
```

}

Other model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_dominio")
public class Dominio {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "dom_codigo")
private Long codigo;

@Column(name="dom_nome", nullable = false)
private String nome;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "dominio")
private List<ElementoDominio> elementosDominio;

//getters and setters
```

}

And finally:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_elemento_dominio")
public class ElementoDominio {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ele_dom_codigo")
private Long codigo; 


@Column(name="ele_dom_label", nullable = false)
private String label;

@Column(name="ele_dom_esta_na_pesquisa", nullable = false)
private boolean estaNaPesquisa;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "dom_codigo", nullable = false)
private Dominio dominio;

//getters and setters
}
```

In my method 'incluiNaPesquisa' which is getting null as parameter. I do not know the reason since my screen is rendering the list and showing each of the labels. If I send AtributoDaPesquisa as parameter, I did not receive null pointer, but the object.

Comment: Is it related to the `p:selectManyCheckbox`? e.g. did you try with a plain jsf `h:selectManyCheckbox`?

Comment: Yeah, I already tried. The same exception happens

Comment: So then changing that in the question and removing the PrimeFaces tag already narrows it down...

Comment: I just removed. Any other sugestion?

Comment: `<p:selectManyCheckbox id="gridQueryResult" layout="grid" columns="2">` does not have a `value` attribute

Comment: Actually does not, because I do not need to save the result, just access the object to change its attribute. For this reason I'm passing the object as parameter in ajax method

Comment: You are getting a `null pointer` becuase the `listner` attribute of `f:ajax` component accepts an `AjaxBehaviourEvent` as a parameter. What do you want to do actually Tathiana?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm interacting in a list that has child objects which, in turn, also has child elements. That is, 'adp' has a 'dominio' that has a list of 'elementos'. The object that is the grandson of 'ADP' ('elemento'), has among other attributes, a Boolean is initialized to false. These elements are displayed on the screen as selectManyCheckbox items. I want it when the user selects the respective element, it is set to true.respective element, it is set to true.